# Can you lol in a question or answer?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

Is it acceptable to have `lol` or even `haha` in either a question or an answer?

The words are just useless noise in either the question or answer... and distract from what the user is saying. lol, I can't see how it can help anyone understand the question better... or even the answer.

So does this mean, it is acceptable to edit and remove `lol` from questions and/or answers?

However, the only thing I could see it adding is an uplifting beat or mood to a question and/or answer.

Comment: Don't live by absolute rules, but 99% of the time its noise

Comment: [This question makes me lol](http://cdn-www.i-am-bored.com/media/65813_drowncallcopslaugh.jpg)

Comment: I don't see what's funny 'bout my code what don't work!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Such content is noise, and can indeed be edited out of a question or answer along with other chatty content that doesn't contribute to the value of the post.

Comments, by design, are a bit less formal, and somewhat more chatty, so it's not really a problem there as long as it's not getting excessive.

Comment: Just out of curiosity... would you consider `hope this helps` or `thanks in advance` as noise?

Comment: @Arian, [very yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/135887).